# How to get parent element inside ng-include when iterating in ng-repeat recursively

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a recursive ng-repeat element, and trying to manipulate things has turned into a nightmare, because I don't have reference to the parent I'm iterating over.

The ng-repeat looks like this:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in value"
```

Remember It's recursive, so each value in value becomes the new value, so I can't just use the  "in" value from ng-repeat. I want to do such things as checking if the parent is an array, but $parent is some weird thing, not the parent element of the current iteration value.

Some examples of things I want to do is:

```
ng-show="isArray(parent)"
ng-click="delete(parent, $index)"
```

(as an example of what I'm doing as a work around, I've had to add an ___ISARRAYELEMENT___ property to each of my array elements, just to know that it's in an array >.>;;)

EDIT: Basically I want to know if there is any convenient meta data in an ng-repeat context that I'm missing.

EDIT: Ok here is the html in it's entirety:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>JSON CRUD</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angularjsoncrud.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="node.html">
        <button ng-click="minimized = !minimized" ng-show="!isLeaf(value)" ng-init="minimized=false" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': minimized, 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': !minimized}">-</button>
        <input ng-model="value.___KEY___" ng-if="!isArrayElement(value)" />
        <input ng-if="isLeaf(value)" ng-model="value.___VALUE___" />
        <ul ng-if="!isLeaf(value)" ng-show="!minimized">
            <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in value" ng-if="key != '___KEY___' && key != '___ISARRAY___'" ng-include="'node.html'"></li>
            <button type="button" ng-if="isArray(value)" ng-click="addToArray(value)">Add Element</button>
        </ul>
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Application" ng-controller="jsoncrudctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in json" ng-include="'node.html'"></li>
    </ul>
    <pre>{{stringify(json)}}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

One thing I would like to do is replace isArrayElement(value) with isArray(parent), because isArrayElement relies on meta data I added to the array, which I would prefer to not have to add.

Comment: Can you post an example of the array/object you're iterating over?

Comment: I suppose. Here is the object I'm using as a sample, and remember I'm recursing through it. It's not just one level:

var json = { 
      field1: "some text",
      array1: ["an", "array"],
      obj1: {
         key1: 8,
         key2: "more text",
      },  
      field2: "loremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremips",
   };

I'll post the whole html in my main post.

Comment: for example (key value in values), i think you can check the "values" in controller, and set values=[] if not an array, so the ng-repeat will not loop

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each element.
`ng-include` also creates a new scope.

When you use `ng-include` together with `ng-repeat`, there are 2 scopes created for each element:

- Scope created by `ng-repeat` for current element. This scope holds the current element in the iteration.
- **Child scope** created by `ng-include` which **inherits** from `ng-repeat`'s created scope.

The `$parent` property of current scope allows you to access its parent scope.

Essentially, scope created by `ng-include` is empty, when you access `value` and `key` in your `node.html`, it actually access the ***inherited values*** from parent scope created by `ng-repeat`.

In your node.html, accessing `{{value}}` is actually the same as `{{$parent.value}}`. Therefore if you need to access the parent of the current element, you have to do one step further by accessing `{{$parent.$parent.value}}`

This [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dqrb5/1/) will clear things up:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="node.html">
        <div>
            Current: key = {{key}}, value = {{value}}
        </div>
        <div>
            Current (using $parent): key = {{$parent.key}}, value = {{$parent.value}}
        </div>
         <div>
             Parent: key = {{$parent.$parent.key}}, value = {{$parent.$parent.value}}, isArray: {{isArray($parent.$parent.value)}}
        </div>
        <ul ng-if="isObject(value)"> //only iterate over object to avoid problems when iterating a string
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in value" ng-include="'node.html'"></li>            
        </ul>
    </script>
```

If you need to simplify the way to access the parent, you could try initializing the parent using `onload` of `ng-include`. Like this:

In your top level, there is no `ng-if` => only 2 level deep

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in json" 
     ng-include="'node.html'" onload="parent=$parent.$parent"></li>
</ul>
```

In your sub levels, there is `ng-if` => 3 levels deep:

```
    <ul ng-if="isObject(value)">
        <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in value" 
ng-include="'node.html'" onload="parent=$parent.$parent.$parent"></li>            
    </ul>
```

Inside the template, you could access the parent using `parent`, grandparent using `parent.parent` and so on.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C6E3k/1/)

Comment: hmmmm... your example was very helpful, because I decided to try more $parents deep. also I understand now the context includes value [it isn't value itsself].

Still, I'm a bit confused. In order to get the parent of an element in an array I had to do $parent.$parent.$parent.$parent, yet any elements in the base object reference the parent using $parent.$parent.$parent.

You've answered my question (Thank you :)), but I'm wondering if you know if there is any way to fix my scope? Writing $parent.$parent.$parent.$parent looks a tad messy ;)

Comment: ah, it seems ng-if adds context as well. That explains the 3, with ng-repeat, ng-include and ng-if. But sometimes it takes two $parents deep . It seems my first recursion the parent is only 2 contexts deep, yet every recursion after that is 3 recursions deep to get to the parent.

Comment: @Jason McCarrell: Check my updated answer with a solution to make the code cleaner, reduce the `$parent.$parent.$parent..`

Comment: omg i love you. The onload trick worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jason McCarrell: you're wellcome. Happing coding

Answer (score 3):

I would stay away from Angular's `$parent` and all the `$scope` creation and inheritance madness. What you need is to keep a reference to the parent object, not finding how many scopes are in-between `ng-include`'s and `ng-repeat`'s and juggling with `$parent.$parent`. My suggestion is to **explicitly save references** to the values you are interested in, just implement it yourself with custom logic. For example, if you want to expose a value from the parent ng-repeat to the child ng-repeat

```
<!-- Explictly save the value into the parent var -->
<div ng-init="parent = value">
  <!-- Save parent reference and
       update the parent var to point to the new value -->
  <div ng-repeat="(k,value) in value"
       ng-init="value._parent = parent; parent = value;"> 
    <div ng-repeat="(k,value) in value"
         ng-init="value._parent = parent">
      <button ng-click="doSomething(value)"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your javascript code you can access all parents recursively

```
function doSomething(value){
  parent1 = value._parent;
  parent2 = parent1._parent;
}
```

Same code with `ng-include`

```
<div ng-init="parent = value">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in value"
       ng-init="value._parent = parent; parent = value;"
       ng-include="'node.html'">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="node.html">
  <div ng-if="!isLeaf(value)"
       ng-repeat="(key,value) in value"
       ng-init="value._parent = parent; parent = value;"
       ng-include="'node.html'"> 

  <button ng-if="isLeaf(value)" ng-click="doSomething(value)"></button>
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think mutating my object is a good idea. I just got away from that =P

Comment: I don't see a reason against "mutating" your object, I think the addition of a parent is good object-oriented practise. Also, angular often attaches additional attributes (prepended with $) to objects. In any case I used the `_parent` attribute as convenience, you may as well use another variable to store your parents recursion. Something like `ng-init="parent = {value: value, parent: parent};"`

Comment: Aren't you basically re-implementing Angular's own $parent property with your own `_parent`? I find this a bit awkward.