# Angular.js - include a fragment of template in template

Tags: django, angularjs, templates

I have 3 templates:
- main template for rendering some basic stuff,
- second template which renders whole tree
- third template which should render each eleement of that tree

When I include row_renderer.html then my variable called subItem is not visible in included template. When I copy that template to second template called nodes_renderer.html then everything seems fine.

How do I pass subItem variable to row_renderer.html?

Main template

```
    {% verbatim %}
    <div ui-tree data-drag-enabled="false" class="">
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="list">
            <li ng-repeat="item in list" ui-tree-node class="table">
                <div ui-tree-handle class="header row" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        {{item.name}} ({{item.submission_count}})
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                        <i class="icon" ng-class="{'icon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'icon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></i>
                        {{item.last_submission_date}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="#" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-file"></i> Pobierz raport</a>
                        <a href="#" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-times"></i> Zakończ zgłoszenie</a>
                        <a href="#" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i> Wyślij SMS</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.children">
                    <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.children" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">

                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    {% endverbatim %}
```

Last fragment of main template:

```
                <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.children">
                    <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.children" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">

                    </li>
                </ol>
```

nodes_renderer.html

```
    {% verbatim %}
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
        <div ui-tree-handle class="row" ng-include="'row_renderer.html'" >

        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="subItem.children">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in subItem.children" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
        </li>
        </ol>
        </div>
    </script>
    {% endverbatim %}
```

row_renderer.html - reusable template

```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="row_renderer.html">

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12" >
        Rodzaj Awarii: {{subItem.type_name}}
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        {{subItem.name}} ({{subItem.submission_count}})
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
        <i class="icon" ng-if="subItem.children" ng-class="{'icon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'icon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></i>
        {{subItem.last_submission_date}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
        <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-star"></i> Przypisz do mnie</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-file"></i> Pobierz raport</a>
        <a href="#" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-times"></i> Zakończ zgłoszenie</a>
        <a href="#" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i> Wyślij SMS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: Cześć Efrin, could extend your code? From what I can tell the template that doesn't receive the variable might be out of controller scope that's why it's not working

Comment: My mistake was totally stupid :) I forgot to wrap row_render with {% verbatim %} tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each element, `ng-include` also creates a new scope.

In the case of `nodes_renderer.html`, you use `subItem` which is **inherited** from your parent scope when you specify `ng-repeat="subItem in item.children"`. That's why it works for `nodes_renderer.html`

> How do I pass subItem variable to row_renderer.html?

Try `onload="subItem=$parent.PropertyToPass"` :

```
<div ui-tree-handle class="row" ng-include="'row_renderer.html'" onload="subItem=$parent.PropertyToPass">
```

For more information: [How to get parent element inside ng-include when iterating in ng-repeat recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876358/how-to-get-parent-element-inside-ng-include-when-iterating-in-ng-repeat-recursiv/20929523#20929523)

Comment: My mistake was totally stupid :) I forgot to wrap row_render with {% verbatim %} tag :) but your onload trick will be really useful.